# Away3d 4, creating a flat shaded material

Tags: actionscript-3, away3d

I'm currently trying to create a "flat" shaded ColorMaterial inside of Away3d 4 to use as a mesh on a loaded .obj file.

This is a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve. The flat shaded model is on the left.
[image: This is a screenshot of what I'm trying to achieve. The flat shaded model is on the left.]

I loaded the same .obj file I’m working with in Away into a program called MeshLab. MeshLab has two settings for Render Mode, flat or smooth.

The Flat render mode is on the left and smooth is on the right. When I load my .obj into Away3D the result looks exactly like MeshLab’s smooth render mode.

In order to get a flat result I’ve tried to set the smooth flag on my ColorMaterial to false but that doesn’t seem to change anything.
http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/materials/MaterialBase.html

I’m now starting to look into the materials shadowMethod because I was able to find a smooth boolean on ShadingMethodBase although I’m honestly not sure if this is where you would handle this.

http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/materials/DefaultMaterialBase.html#shadowMethod
http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/materials/methods/ShadingMethodBase.html

Below is the code for creating my light and light picker,

```
dL = new DirectionalLight();
dL.diffuse = 20;
dL.ambient=.6;
dL.specular=15

scene.addChild(dL);

lightPicker= new StaticLightPicker([dL]);
dL.direction = new Vector3D(0,1,-2);
```

And this is my material, I've tried playing around with most of it's properties:

```
primitiveMaterial = new ColorMaterial(0xcccccc);
primitiveMaterial.smooth = false;
primitiveMaterial.bothSides = false;
//primitiveMaterial.gloss = 800;
//primitiveMaterial.diffuseLightSources = LightSources.LIGHTS;
primitiveMaterial.diffuseMethod.alphaThreshold = .3;
primitiveMaterial.ambient =.2;
primitiveMaterial.lightPicker=lightPicker;
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ColorMaterial has no smooth attribute because it hasn't texture and smooth indicates whether or not any used textures should use smoothing.  Most likely smooth attribute is inherited from [MaterialBase](http://away3d.com/livedocs/away3d/4.0/away3d/materials/MaterialBase.html) and have no affect. 
Your problem is in the [normal vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_%28geometry%29) when surface is flat they are normals, when it is smoothed they are blended so it appears smoother. 
Im guessing the problem might be in [obj](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) file. If it has no normals Away3d might generate them by it self ass well as MeshLab but Away3d apparently doing it only in smoothed mode by default. Or obj file contain smoothed normals and MeshLab overriding them in flat mode.
Open obj file with text editor and look for normals, try another obj file with flat surface. 
But i might be wrong.

[Here is smoothed obj](http://pastebin.com/Ltvid8Yd)

[And this one is flat](http://pastebin.com/VG2MCwUn)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is probably the Explode class.
Call `Explode.apply(<your loaded mesh>)` to remove the smoothed normals.